# Hide div onclick in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

What is the Vue.js equivalent of the following jQuery?

```
$('.btn').click(function(){  $('.hideMe').hide()  });
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

Answer (score 47, accepted):

jQuery works out of the box, Vue.js does not. To initialize Vue.js component or App you must bind that component with its data to one specific HTML tag inside your template.

In this example the specified element is `<div id="app"></div>` and is targeted through `el: #app`. This you will know from jQuery.

After you declare some variable that holds the toggle state, in this case, `isHidden`, the initial state is `false` and has to be declared inside the `data` object.

The rest is Vue-specific code like `v-on:click=""` and `v-if=""`. For a better understanding please read the documentation of Vue.js:

- [The Vue Instance](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html)
- [Template Syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html)
- [Event Handling](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Listening-to-Events)
- [Conditionals](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)

**Note:** consider reading the whole or at least longer parts of the documentation for better understanding.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    isHidden: false
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="isHidden = true">Hide the text below</button>
  <button v-on:click="isHidden = !isHidden">Toggle hide and show</button>
  
  <h1 v-if="!isHidden">Hide me on click event!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Just made this the answer instead of the other answer as this was the one that solved what I needed. Thanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 23):

This is a very basic Vue question. I suggest your read the guide, even the first page will answer your question.

However, if you still need the answer this is how you hide/show elements in Vue.

```js
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data () {
   return {
     toggle: true
   }
 },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.3/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click='toggle = !toggle'> click here </button>
  <div v-show='toggle'>showing</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did it in a similar way initially, but I had some syntax issues with the @click.

Answer (score 5):

```
<div>
    <div>

        <button v-on:click="isHidden = !isHidden">Toggle hide and show</button>

        <h1 v-if="!isHidden">Hide me on click event!</h1>
    </div>
</div>

name: "Modal",
    data () {
        return {
            isHidden: false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The up-voted answer is definitely a way to do it, but when I was trying to do this it was with a dynamic array instead of a single `Div`, so a single static `Vue` variable wouldn't quite cut it.

As @samayo mentions, there isn't a difference between the hide action from `jQuery vs Vue`, so another way to do this is to trigger the `jQuery` through the `@click` function.

The `Vue` Dev kit will tell you not to mix JS inline with `@click` events and I had the same problem as @user9046370 trying to put the `jQuery` command inline with `@click`, so anyway,

**Here's another way to do this:**

```html
<tr v-for="Obj1,index in Array1">
    <td >{{index}}</td>
    <td >
        <a @click="ToggleDiv('THEDiv-'+index)">Show/Hide List</a><BR>
        <div style='display:none;' :id="'THEDiv-'+index" >
            <ul><li v-for="Obj2 in Array2">{{Obj2}}</li></ul>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```js
Method:
ToggleDiv: function(txtDivID)
{
    $("#"+txtDivID).toggle(400);
},
```

The other perk of this is that if you want to use fancy `jQuery` transitions you can with this method.

Answer (score -1):

```
<template>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button"><i class="fas fa-filter" @click="showFilter = !showFilter"></i></button>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        methods:{
            showFilter() {
                eventHub.$emit('show-guest-advanced-filter');
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

But it's not worked this method.

```
<template>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button"><i class="fas fa-filter" @click="filtersMethod"></i></button>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            filter: true,
        }),

        methods: {
            showFilter() {
                eventHub.$emit('show-guest-advanced-filter');
                this.filter = false;
            },

            hideFilter() {
                eventHub.$emit('hide-guest-advanced-filter');
                this.filter = true;
            },

            filtersMethod() {
                return this.filter ? this.showFilter() : this.hideFilter();
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

This is worked.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22215674)

Comment: I solved the problem, but I shared it for guidance. It would be more useful if you share the truth rather than writing it up.