# How to Toggle Visibility of VueJs Component?

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-component

In my Laravel App, I have a button on Blade template to show/hide a Vue Component. I tried with the following with the help of the following code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48929139/hide-div-onclick-in-vue). I get following error:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "isShow" is not defined on the instance
> but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
> reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
> initializing the property. See:
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
 <button v-on:click="isShow = !isShow">Toggle hide and show</button>
 <site-email  v-if="isShow"></site-email>
@endsection
```

Component

```
 <template>
    <div class="label label-info"> {{domain}}'s Email</div>
 <template>

 <script>
  export default {
    data(){
      return {
          isShow : false,
        }
    }
 }
 </script>

I will highly appreciate your help.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue's reactive data property is `Component scope`.

You are now accessing `isShow` outside of the component, so Vue can't access the property.

My suggest: You may insert the button in `<site-email>` component.

```
 <template>
    <button v-on:click="isShow = !isShow">Toggle hide and show</button>
    <div v-show="isShow" class="label label-info"> {{domain}}'s Email</div>
 <template>

 <script>
  export default {
    data(){
      return {
          isShow : false,
        }
    }
 }
 </script>
```

Or, if you don't want to include the button in the component, you have to use a method to communicate between components like "Event bus", "[.sync props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier)"